# Is it possible to use the at command to schedule a job to run at a given timestamp?

Tags: cron, time, timestamps, at

I want to schedule a file to run using the `at` command, as described in [this](http://aplawrence.com/BDD/bbcronbasics.html) tutorial. I see that the `at` command supports the posix format -- but I don't see any mention of timestamps. Surely it is possible to schedule a job at a given timestamp.

```
$ man at | grep timestamp
```

Comment: google `epoch cron`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `usr/share/doc/at/timespec`, it doesn't look like it. But you can always use `date` to convert your timestamp, eg:

```
at "$(date --date=@1393419435 +'%H:%M %D')"
```

`date` takes a timestamp in seconds, so don't forget to trim fractions of seconds if needed.